# How to use a filename other than main.cpp for the main() method in a c++ executable

Tags: c++, eclipse, program-entry-point

I'm using Eclipse IDE but there is a linking error while trying to build the project without a main.cpp file.

I know that what i'm trying to do is possible because the HelloWorld example has its main() method inside HelloWorld.cpp but i can't find what i need to change inside the eclipse IDE project building parameters.

That being said, is there any drawback in having the main() method in a file different than main.cpp in one project?

Thanks

Edit: After a computer reboot the problem never appeared again. I haven't been able to reproduce it since then so it looks like it wasn't a coding problem or conventional configuration issue. The normal behaviour is as described in the marked answer to this question.

Comment: What does the link error say? You should be able to call the file with `main` in anything you like (to a point)

Comment: This is the error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1. How do i call the file where the main method is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse will check every file in the project for `main`, but not your entire harddisk. Did you add the file with `main` to your project?

Comment: Yes, inside a code folder named "scr".

Comment: @SaintJob2.0 did you check that the file is actually building? (try putting an #error in it)

Comment: How did you add the file to your project?

Comment: Finally rebooting solved the problem so i'm closing this questions. Thanks and sorry.